# MEAN failed to deploy

Tags: google-compute-engine, mean

I tried to deploy MEAN on the Google Developers Console and it keeps on failing. I tried change the zone and still doesn't work.

```
Creating deployment
Jan 25, 2015, 10:16:40 PM
meanStackBox: PENDING
Jan 25, 2015, 10:16:51 PM ... Jan 25, 2015, 10:21:04 PM
meanStackBox: DEPLOYING
Jan 25, 2015, 10:21:15 PM
meanStackBox: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
Replica mean-o3nb failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.
```

Is there any work arounds?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a statement of fact not a question.

Comment: really @ta.speot.is :I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Bitnami's prebuilt MEAN stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/mean/cloud/google) to deploy MEAN on Google Compute Engine.